# JavaSpark Secure SSL Connection

Tags: java, spark-java

Trying to do a "secure" connection using JavaSpark.

I have a CRT certificate in a Java Keystore, but code like this gives me a server error:

```
secure("/keystore.jks", "thepassword",
                            "trusted-certificate-file-name", "thepassword");
```

The "trusted-certificate-file-name" is the name inside the keystore file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry - Above question is for the Java Spark framework not Apache-spark.

Comment: what does the error message look like?

Comment: It just says: "SERVER ERROR".

Since the firewall is wide open (don't tell anyone ... LOL), I "think" the problem might be that I created the CSR outside of Keystore but later imported the received CRT file into it. So, possibly the two files are out of sync?  I'm not exactly sure what needs to be in the Keystore. Just the trusted certificate or do I also need the CSR key?

Tomcat won't connect on port 8443 either so there's something basically wrong here.

Thanks,